# nested views much slower in Pg 9.3.4 than 8.4.8

Tags: performance, nested, view, postgresql-9.3

We recently upgraded from Pg 8.4 to 9.3 and soon noticed that nested views which ran in a few seconds in 8.4 take 100 times longer or never complete w/in a reasonable (10 min) amount of time in 9.3.

explain returns immediately while explain(analyze,buffers) was still running 20 minutes after submitting the query.

See http://explain.depesz.com/s/Bn3v for the 9.3 explain output nicely formatted.

We saw the same results on a VM test platform and on a large (24GB mem, 900GB disk) prod server.

Has anyone seen similar behavior?

Comment: Don't suppose there's any chance of seeing the query plan from 8.4 if you still have it around? That top level nested loop node is going to be a killer in the plan you showed, especially over three layers of inner nested loops. If you `SET enable_indexonlyscan = false` for testing purposes only, do you get a better plan? What about `SET enable_nestloop = false`? (Do NOT use these to "fix" the problem; they're to diagnose issues only). If you get a better plan please post `explain (buffers,verbose,analyze)` for it.

Comment: I ran it on 8.4 with the default settings but despesz wouldn't accept the entire plan so here is the first 50 or so lines: http://explain.depesz.com/s/jPC

Comment: I ran it on 9.3 with the changes you recommend:
set enable_indexonlycan = FALSE
set enable_nestloop = FALSE
with explain and not explain (buffers, verbose, analyze) because explain (buffers, verbose, analyze) didn't finish in a reasonable amount of time, i.e, < 30 seconds.
Here's the plan http://explain.depesz.com/s/BuGn

Comment: Did you run ANALYZE database-wide after the upgrade? Please do so and see if the plans changes and if it gets better.

Comment: @MatheusOl  ANALYZE did greatly improve performance in some, but not all cases.  In one experiment execution time dropped from 130 seconds to 5.  Would differences in the planner between 8.4 and 9.x account for the discrepancies in execution time?  Unfortunately we do not have an 8.4 dump to restore to permit side-by-side comparsion of the two execution.plans.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.